# R: Convert daily returns to monthly returns

Tags: r, zoo, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I have an xts of daily *returns* and I'd like to convert it to monthly returns.

I can find tonnes of threads to convert daily *prices* to period returns, but I need to convert daily *returns*.

Having followed the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638954/reformat-daily-stock-and-return-data-to-weekly-monthly/33639798#33639798) thread, which works well, I noticed that the returns are not geometric, they're arithmetic.

Therefore, I need something like cumprod(x+1)^(365/12)-1.

However, replacing sum(cx) with that doesn't work.

Here's my code as it stands:

```
 # Generate data like the type I'm working with    
    testdata <- cbind(rnorm(100,0.0001,0.01),rnorm(100,0.0001,0.01))
    testdata <- as.xts(testdata, order.by = seq(Sys.Date()-99,Sys.Date(),1))


   myFun <- function(x) {
    # need coredata, so c.xts will not be dispatched
     cx <- coredata(x)
     Return = sum(cx)
     }

   MonthlyReturns <- NULL
   for (i in 1:ncol(testdata)){
     MonthlyReturns <- cbind(MonthlyReturns,period.apply(testdata[,i], endpoints(testdata[,i], "months"), 
     myFun))
   }
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT - The output should be the same format as the input - a table of monthly returns instead of daily. Either xts or dataframe / matrix.

EDIT - For those interested in the origin of the returns matrix, I'm using the `Return.annualized` function from the Performance Analytics package as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/zachmayer/1222639/4401262eb14d642d7380f42e3e5838031fdd7315). (Actually, I've modified it by using `Return.cumulative`, which is much faster). So yes, although I do have a price matrix and can easily calculate monthly returns from that, I have additional columns in my daily returns matrix from other calculations, hence I need to convert the daily returns, not the daily prices.

Comment: Can you share what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Updated original post. Basically the output should be the same as input, except by month instead of by day.

Comment: To clarify `returns`, this is already calculated against the `basis`? I guess a dput() would be useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to the accepted solution a much faster way ( > 5 times faster ) to get monthly returns is to combine the `aggregate` function with `cumprod`.

```
 system.time(aggregate(testdata,as.yearmon,function(x) tail(cumprod(1 + x) -1,1)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.021   0.002   0.023 
 system.time(apply.monthly(testdata, Return.cumulative))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.116   0.002   0.118
```

data:

```
testdata <- as.xts(cbind(rnorm(10000,0.0001,0.01),rnorm(100,0.0001,0.01)), order.by = seq(Sys.Date()-9999,Sys.Date(),1))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is 2.5x faster on my particular data - every little helps!

Comment: 7 times on my laptop, lol. (Alienware M17) `user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02` vs. `user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.00    0.14`

Answer (score 3):

Since you want monthly cumulative daily returns, we can apply the `Return.cumulative` function from `PerformanceAnalytics` on a monthly basis using the `apply.monthly` function from `xts`. This gives you what you want. Nice simple solution, no need to write your own function.

```r
library(PerformanceAnalytics) # for Return.cumulative function
library(quantmod) # loads xts which has apply.monthly function 

MonthlyReturns <- apply.monthly(testdata, Return.cumulative)
MonthlyReturns
                  [,1]         [,2]
2020-01-31 -0.09507546 -0.090607862
2020-02-29  0.04056104  0.001859122
2020-03-31  0.01451002  0.117231568
2020-04-12  0.01502248  0.026660881
```

Comment: Heh, I'm such a dumbass! I'd used this function elsewhere, so don't know why I didn't think to use it here too... Thanks!